# Codeception code coverage on local setup for functional test

Tags: php, selenium, code-coverage, xdebug, codeception

I am using codeception with `Selenium` webdriver to do functional tests for my application. I would like to generate code coverage report for my automation test code locally on my system. I looked at http://laravelista.com/codeception-code-coverage-and-laravel and http://codeception.com/docs/11-Codecoverage#.VnnFUFIcYQs. I have enabled coverage in `codeception.yml` file.

Regarding `XDebug`, since I am using windows machine, I downloaded `php_xdebug-2.4.0rc3-5.6-vc11.dll` from http://xdebug.org/download.php and `set zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.4.0rc3-5.6-vc11.dll` in `php.ini` file.

I am still getting this error :--

```
 [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]
  file_get_contents(http://mywebsite.com/beta//c3/report/clear
  ): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

`c3.php` I thought is for remote code coverage. I have not set any remote parameters. Why is codeception looking for `c3` still? Is it so hard to generate a coverage report for automated functional tests with codeception? I know it was quite simple with `PHPUnit`. I don't understand. An help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are doing a remote code coverage on a local server.

Comment: I don't intend to do remote coverage. I have set remote to false in codeception.yml.  I am doing functional test on Firefox using selenium. My automation script code is present locally on my machine. I want to check code coverage of my automation code which is not on webserver.

Comment: Selenium testing is remote by definition, because it makes requests via HTTP. If you want to do a local functional testing, use a framework module.

Comment: You are right. So, I will have to do remote code coverage setup is it then? Where do I put the c3 file in that case?  What is the c3 URL?